# AWS CDK enable API Gateway's raw request body for cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk, api-gateway

I have an AWS API Gateway and this is my CDK code:

```
const api = new aws_apigateway.RestApi(this, 'kartal', {
    restApiName: "kartal",
    deployOptions: {
        stageName: process.env.ENVIRONMENT,
        loggingLevel: aws_apigateway.MethodLoggingLevel.INFO,
        metricsEnabled: true,
        accessLogFormat: aws_apigateway.AccessLogFormat.custom(JSON.stringify({
            requestId: aws_apigateway.AccessLogField.contextRequestId(),
            ip: aws_apigateway.AccessLogField.contextIdentitySourceIp(),
            requestTime: aws_apigateway.AccessLogField.contextRequestTime(),
            resourcePath: aws_apigateway.AccessLogField.contextResourcePath(),
            method: aws_apigateway.AccessLogField.contextHttpMethod(),
            error: aws_apigateway.AccessLogField.contextErrorMessage(),
            validationError: aws_apigateway.AccessLogField.contextErrorValidationErrorString(),
            status: aws_apigateway.AccessLogField.contextStatus()
         })),
        accessLogDestination: new aws_apigateway.LogGroupLogDestination(apigwLogGroup)
    },
})
```

1. Is that possible to log API Gateway's raw request into Cloudwatch using CDK?
2. Is that possible to activate **Full Request and Response Logs** flag using CDK? I couldn't find any reference into the CDK documentation. [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.AccessLogField.html)
3. If both negative, how can I log API Gateway's raw requests?

[image: api gateway cloudwatch]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to **activate Full Request and Response Logs** in the CDK, dataTraceEnabled flag in the deployOptions.

```js
const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'books', {
  cloudWatchRole: true,
  deployOptions: {
    loggingLevel: apigateway.MethodLoggingLevel.INFO,
    dataTraceEnabled: true
  }
})
```

Comment: If this answer best solved your issue, then consider marking it as correct to help guide others with the same issue in the future.