# access body of requests in AWS with Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using lambda to PUT/PATCH/GET/DELETE stuff.

I need to store and access the logs of my users to see what happen when something goes wrong.

I'm actually clicking on every cloudwatch to find the informations I need, I want to search them with a request.

Is there a db we can use with cloudwatch to store body informations and access them quickly ?

(I can do it manually by sending my body into a db in the beginning of all my lambda but I hope this is already integer in the cloudwatch management)

Comment: CloudWatch Log Insight queries? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html

Comment: @Utopion 
Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76128604/aws-cdk-enable-api-gateways-raw-request-body-for-cloudwatch. Enabling this option will create a dedicated log group where all requests with body will be found

Comment: There's no database for the requests. The closest thing you have out of the box is CloudWatch logs, which you are already using. If you need to perform more advanced searches and analytics on your logs AWS recommends spinning up an OpenSearch cluster and streaming the logs over to there using a Lambda function that is triggered on new CloudWatch log records. That of course adds a lot of expense.